# Trying to understand charAt method inside an integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to understand, how can we use a string element inside the integer array.
I am solving one of the array related question where I am trying to store frequency of characters in a string.

```
int[] letters = new int[128];
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
    letters[s.charAt(i)] =  letters[s.charAt(i)] + 1;    
}
```

My question is, since letters is an integer array, s.charAt(i) will return a string character.
I am printing out, letter[s.charAt(i)] which lets say is letters['a'] which does print out a number. But by using charAt its not. How can we access the char as an index?

Comment: You're mistaken, `letters['a']` will not throw an error. `letters[a]` would (unknown symbol `a`), and `letters["a"]` would, but `charAt()` returns a `char`, not a variable and not a `String`.

Comment: @Andreas So how can a char be index or the array ? Lets say letters['a']

Comment: `String` cannot be an index, but the code is not trying to use a `String` as an index, it is using a `char` as an index.

Comment: @Andreas should an index of an array be numeric ?

Comment: It is, because a `char` is a numeric value (0-65535) with the Unicode code point. Actually, it's a UTF-16 value, but ignore that for now. See: [The Java™ Tutorials - Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: @Andreas You mean to say, letters['a'] is interpreted as letters['some numeric value'] ?

Comment: Try `System.out.println((int) 'a');` and see what happens. *Hint:* It'll print the ASCII/Unicode value of [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A' (U+0061)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221300/discussion-between-jainam-shah-and-andreas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to understand, how can we use a string element inside the integer array.

It depends on what you mean in *use*. If you want to store a string value into integer array - you cannot. Neither `int[]` or `Ingeter[]` will allow you to store any string element in them. You will get a compile-time error, something like:

```
java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int
```

> I am printing out, letter[s.charAt(i)] which lets say is letters['a']

String#charAt(int) returns a single character, and what you're trying to do, is to access your `letters` array's slot with a character index, which, in turn, would also stop your compilation process with the message:

```
java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   variable yourCharacter
```

> How can we access the char as an index?

You cannot. Index of any array is always a positive integer number.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say your string is

```
String str = "stack"
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
System.out.println(str.charAt(i))
}
```

// Signature of charAt method is, charAt(int index). Here, it takes the index of the string as referred by i and prints the character. Your assumption is slightly wrong. You can refer to String class of the official Java documentation to get the better understanding of the methods arguments, what it does and what it returns.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html